How to interpret results of a GLM from a double factor experimental design
I have an experiment with two factors "Enzyme", and "FeedMixture" which has 4 different levels. "FeedMixture", is a variable of type factor. Below I simulate a response variable and provide an example of my df:
set.seed(123) 
num_reads <- 84 
response <- round(rnorm(num_reads, mean = 50, sd =20)) 
response <- pmax(pmin(response, 100), 0) 
FM <- sample(c("_A","_B", "_C", "_D"), num_reads, replace = TRUE) 
Enzyme <- sample(c(500,1500, 3000), num_reads, replace = TRUE) 
df <- data.frame(r_var = response, FM = FM, Enzyme = Enzyme) 
rm<-glm(r_var~FM+Enzyme+FM:Enzyme,data = df)

The results look as follows:
Call:  glm(formula = r_var ~ FM + Enzyme + FM:Enzyme, data = df)

Coefficients:(Intercept)   FM_B     FM_C      FM_D       Enzyme  FM_B:Enzyme  FM_D:Enzyme  FM_C:Enzyme  
              34.223841 19.199688 4.867659  26.737532   0.006747  -0.009241    -0.002555   -0.009512       

Degrees of Freedom: 83 Total (i.e. Null);  76 Residual Null Deviance:    32450  Residual Deviance: 29600    AIC: 749

I have two questions, please :)
I understand that since "FM" is a factor the "FM_A" is taken to mean the Intercept, therefore we only have estimates for "Intercept", "FM_B", "FM_C" and "FM_D".
1.- How should I interpret the estimate "Enzyme"?, is it only the estimate for the factor "Enzyme"? or is it then the interaction "Enzyme:Intercept"?. Whichever it is, where is the otherone?
2.- Can I build the equations with those estimates or shall forcedly I get the lsmeans? how to decide that?
